# Window box notifications

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way I can create a notification dialog box that can be run from a bash shell script in Linux to notify the user when something needs attention by bringing it to the top above all the other open windows?

I did have a look at the `notify-send` command, but that isn't what I'm really looking for, since it's temporary and expires after a few hundred milliseconds of displaying and doesn't require a users input as a non-clickable item.

is there a way I can achieve this? I don't think this would be too difficult to do. I did have a search around on Google but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for to the functions I want to make in a bash script since this will be run from right-click context menu with no need to use Terminal directly to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching something like a windows **msgbox** you can use e.g. [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/)

```
zenity --info --text="I need your attention"
```

With KDE you can use **kdialog**

```
kdialog --msgbox "Here Again.\n I need your attention"
```

`kdialog --help` to have a list of option, or `man zenity` ... so the usual way to ask informations about a program.

PS> For an *internal bash solution* (if the package `dialog` is installed) you can use e.g.

```
dialog  --msgbox "Ehi hello" 10 30
```

it will act in your terminal.